# Filter Time from Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

i want to filter time i have records 
i wrote query like this query will fetch time between 12:00 Pm and 05:00 Pm

```
Select cs_ClinicName , FromTime ,ToTime from #temp
WHERE (1=1) and
( FromTime between CONVERT(Time,'12:00') and CONVERT(Time,'17:00')
or
ToTime between CONVERT(Time,'12:00') and CONVERT(Time,'17:00') )
```

But it is filtering only this records
Micolaj11111 09:00:00.0000000 13:00:00.0000000

what i a m expecting is it must give all clinic who work between 
between 12:00 Pm and 05:00 Pm
according to the records all clinic work between that time slot 12:00 Pm and 05:00 Pm)

```
Clinic NAME                        FromTime            ToTime
Boyka                          09:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
Clinic Name                    10:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
sleek clini                    10:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
Life Clinic                    10:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
SAiClini                       09:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
jh                             10:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000
Micolaj11111                   09:00:00.0000000    13:00:00.0000000
Dental Clinic                  10:00:00.0000000    19:00:00.0000000
Eye clinic                     09:00:00.0000000    18:00:00.0000000
ryan                           01:00:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
Select cs_ClinicName , FromTime ,ToTime from #temp

 where ((datepart(hh, FromTime) <= 12)  and (datepart(hh, ToTime ) >= 17))
```

Comment: The  above query will show all  records  except                                    Micolaj11111          09:00:00.0000000      13:00:00.0000000

Answer (score 0):

Your query is requesting all the records that have a start or finish time between the given range.  However, you should be looking if any start earlier than, or finish later than the provided range.  Try something like the following if you need to identify any clinics the remain open through the entire time range :

```
Select * FROM #Temp
WHERE FromTime <= CONVERT(Time, '12:00') AND ToTime >= CONVERT(Time, '17:00')
```

If you need to find any clinic which is open within the given time range, try

```
Select * FROM #Temp
WHERE CONVERT(Time,'12:00') <= ToTime
```

Comment: i tried  your query The above query will show all records except Micolaj11111 09:00:00.0000000 13:00:00.0000000 –                             Even Micolaj11111  clinic works between 12:00 Pm and  5 pm

Comment: @surajem updated the query for you.  The earlier query listed all clinics that were open within the *entire* time range.  The new query will search for any which are open at a given time.